# TypeError: Cannot read property "removeAttribute" of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to alert "hello" as soon as a button is clicked. I get the error above on my browser, and as seen in the html below, I put the script link below the button tag so I don't know what causes the error. Any help is appreciated.

receiver.js

```js
$(function(){
    $("#passform").click(function(){
  alert("hello");
  console.log("hello");
 });
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <link href="public/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheets" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <button type="submit" id="passform"></button>

      <script type="scripi/javascript" src="C:/users/owner/desktop/steelVault/public/javascripts/receiver.js"></script>
      <script type="scripi/javascript" src="C:/users/owner/desktop/steelVault/public/javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This may be related to AdBlock extenstion as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143879/cannot-read-property-removeattribute-of-null-cant-find-source-of-it

Comment: Are you trusting what is mentioned over there or tried, because I tried firefox and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `receiver.js` file clearly references jQuery and thus depends on it. As such, you'll need to ensure that you reference jQuery prior to referencing your other files that depend on it :

```
<script type="script/javascript" src="C:/users/owner/desktop/steelVault/public/javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="script/javascript" src="C:/users/owner/desktop/steelVault/public/javascripts/receiver.js"></script>
```

Besides this, I don't see any code that would explicitly reference the `removeAttribute()` function, so there is some code missing from the example or an issue with some of the scripts not loading properly.

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Omitted -->
</head>
<body>
  <button type="submit" id="passform"></button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#passform").click(function() {
        alert('hello');
        console.log('hello');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your jQuery file is actually being loaded properly? Try using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and check for any errors in the Console or Network tabs.

Comment: That may be the case but I don't know how to decode it from the errors that I'm given, and the error that I started with is from my browser tools

Comment: Try using the Network tab. Open the Developer Tools (F12), select the Network tab and keep it open while you refresh the page in question. You should see both of your JS file being loaded and if those look fine (i.e. no 404 errors, etc.) then do the same with the Console tab.

Comment: looks like it's not getting loaded, any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure the path for jQuery is typed exactly as it is referenced in your code? Generally typos are going to be one of the major causes of something like this.

Comment: there were 404 errors before until I decided to put the whole directory in i.e including the root (C:/users/owner/desktop/steelVault/), then it stopped, maybe that affects it somehow

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on chrome? It could be related to AdBlock. Try changing your browser to FireFox and see if you're getting the same error.