# Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null: Cant find source of it

Tags: javascript

Im getting errors over and over again on each of my sites:

```
VM42958:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
(anonymous function) @ VM42958:5
(anonymous function) @ VM42958:20
```

Unfortunately i cant find the source of this error. If i open the related JavaScript lines i find the following:

**VM42958**

```
(function()
{
  var style = document.getElementById("9mr7n8lmeyjxk84i17g5ws714i") ||
              document.documentElement.shadowRoot.getElementById("9mr7n8lmeyjxk84i17g5ws714i");
  style.removeAttribute("id");
  Object.defineProperty(style, "disabled", {value: false, enumerable: true});
  Object.defineProperty(style.sheet, "disabled", {value: false, enumerable: true});
  var deleteRule = CSSStyleSheet.prototype.deleteRule;
  CSSStyleSheet.prototype.deleteRule = function(index)
  {
    if (this != style.sheet)
      deleteRule.call(this, index);
  }
  var removeRule = CSSStyleSheet.prototype.removeRule;
  CSSStyleSheet.prototype.removeRule = function(index)
  {
    if (this != style.sheet)
      removeRule.call(this, index);
  }
})();
```

This is not my code and i have no idea where it is comming from or where it is used. As libraries im using bootstrap, jQuery and Chart.js.

Does somebody know this part of code or is there a way to find the source of this error. i mean directly the line where it is appearing?

The same error occurs in this jsFiddle for example: [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/898kzyp7/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Same problem here. 
For some reason Chrome ADBlock (not plus) was the cause.

Comment: You are right. For some reason ADBlock is causing this problem.

Comment: yes it was the cause.. was doing a lots of nothing.. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried posting an issue at their forum? https://help.getadblock.com/support/tickets/new

Comment: Yes! After disable AdBlock for my domain (localhost) all worked well!

Comment: In my case ADBlock Plus was causing the problem.

Comment: @JorgeCasariego how did you disable it? I tried Firefox it is also throwing the same error.

Comment: @paul Firefox-> tools > Add-ons > extensions (about: addons) page https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes

Answer (score 1):

The `var style = ...` statement gives `null`. You do not have in the document any of the queried elements.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the worst solution ever is to remove AdBlock or disable it.